# GTM & SSGTM gtag hit send by google client tag manager but server not recive

Tags: google-tag-manager

I use Stape as Server and I try to send data from client to server.
On the client debug side, I can see the "gtag hit send" but on server Debug i do not get anything. Whene I use terminal to curl to the server, it works and Page View is coming but not over the google tag manager client.

I checked everything multiple times (GA4 ID, Server URL, Configs). I got access logs from GTM in stape but no GA4 logs except, that one i send via curl (terminal).

I also tryed to publish (server & client) but same result. Any Idea what else I can check or where to finde some thing?

Client is sending gtag hit in debuger with the correct url, but no data on server recived.